# Excel VBA: Check cell contains at least one match on list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to use Excel VBA to check whether a cell on one sheet ("Sheet1") contains all of a cell from a list in a separate sheet ("Sheet2").

So, if A1 in "Sheet1" is "My favourite fruit is apples"
And the list in "Sheet2" (A:A) is:

Pears

Bananas

Grapes

Apples

...

Then I would like cell B1 on "Sheet1" to say "Yes". This will need to loop through all cells with values in A:A on "Sheet1"

I've been trying this with WorksheetFunction.CountIf but can't get this to work as above.

Is anyone able to put me on the right path with this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Concatenate used range of column A (Sheet2) - variable strcatSheet2A in the code.
2. Go through each cell (rng in code) in used range of column A (Sheet1)
3. Split the cell (rng) value, if it's not empty, into array of values.
4. Go through each value (val in code) and if it's not empty search if it's inside strcatSheet2A. If val is inside strcatSheet2A then just write "Yes" and exit the loop (the one that goes through values) and continue with the step 3.

Here is the simplified version of the code

```
Sub NotASub()
    Dim strcatSheet2A As String
    Dim val, rng
    strcatSheet2A = LCase(Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect([Sheet2].Range("A:A"), _
                                             [Sheet2].UsedRange).Value2), vbNullString))

    For Each rng In Intersect([Sheet1].Range("A:A"), [Sheet1].UsedRange)
        If rng.Value <> Empty Then
            For Each val In Split(rng.Value, " ")
                If Len(val) > 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, strcatSheet2A, LCase(Trim(val))) > 0 Then
                        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes"
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next val
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Further explanation:

1. Intersect has self explanatory functionality, here it just makes the code run faster.
2. Transpose is needed because a column is 2D array, and we need 1D to make use of JOIN

Following up on your question from the comment

```
Sub NotASub2()
    Dim A1 As Variant, A2 As Variant
    A1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect([Sheet1].Range("A:A"), _
                             [Sheet1].UsedRange).Value2)
    A2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Intersect([Sheet2].Range("A:A"), _
                             [Sheet2].UsedRange).Value2)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(A1) To UBound(A1)
        For j = LBound(A2) To UBound(A2)
            If Len(A2(j)) > 0 And InStr(1, LCase(A1(i)), LCase(A2(j))) > 0 Then
                [Sheet1].Cells(i, 2).Value = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response on this, it has helped me a lot. I did forget to mention though that there could be two or more words in one of the cells within the list in Sheet2 (i.e. Mince Pies). I was hoping that the code could allow for this by checking that the whole phrase "Mince Pies" is included in the cell in Sheet1. At the moment, I believe it is returning true because Pies appears on Sheet1 on its own. However, I would like this to be false as it is not the same as "Mince Pies". Is there any way I can allow for this in the code you sent? Thanks again!

Comment: If this answers your original question, please consider marking it as such. When it comes to the follow up question, the basic solution would be to simply use columns A from both sheets (a1 = Intersect([Sheet1].range("A:A"), [Sheet1].usedrange).value, the same for a2) and loop through them and do the instr check.

Comment: Thank you. I've not immediately been able to get this loop to work with my code but will keep researching :)

Comment: Check out additional code I've appended. Cheers

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks so much, that is spot on what I was looking for!